# Google Auth Returning Credentials missing Object

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

im new to gcp, and i followed all of the setup instructions, however its returning a weird error:

heres the code:

```py
import google.auth
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Set up the credentials
creds, project = google.auth.default()
creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_info(info=creds)
```

heres the output/error:

```hs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mohit/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/jaiveersstuff:sob:.py", line 7, in <module>
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_info(info=creds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/oauth2/credentials.py", line 387, in from_authorized_user_info
    missing = keys_needed.difference(six.iterkeys(info))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/six.py", line 599, in iterkeys
    return iter(d.keys(**kw))
AttributeError: 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

advice would be appreciated

i havent tried much, as im not sure where to start with, but i expected the code to execute as normal

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by adding this line: `Credentials.from_authorized_user_info`? The previous line already created the credentials object. The `info` parameters should be JSON with `client_id`, `client_secret`, `type`, etc. You are passing a different type of parameter.

Comment: tysm, i just realised my stupidity